# Cloudflare DNS update api returning 'Request body is invalid.' python

Tags: python, python-requests, cloudflare

I'm trying to update a Cloudflare DNS record using the v4 API and a python script, I keep getting a 'Request body is invalid.' error, ive changed quite a few values as they are confidential, so replace `API_KEY`, `EMAIL`, `NEW_IP`, `DOMAIN`, `ZONE_ID` and `RECORD_ID` with their respective values, I've double checked all of them on my end, and they were correct, the code is shown below.

```py
import requests

full_api_key = "Bearer " + "API_KEY"
api_url = f"https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/ZONE_ID/dns_records/RECORD_ID"
    
headers = {
    'x-auth-email': "EMAIL",
    'Authorization': full_api_key,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'      
}
    
data = {
    "content": 'NEW_IP',
    "name": 'DOMAIN',
    "proxied": True,
    "type": 'A',
    "comment" : "DNS Record Auto-updated",
    "tags" : [],
    "ttl": 3600,
}

res = requests.patch(api_url, headers=headers, data=data)

print(res.json())
```

The specific response is a code `400`, that goes as follows:

```
{'result': None, 'success': False, 'errors': [{'code': 9207, 'message': 'Request body is invalid.'}], 'messages': []}
```

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try to use `json=data` instead `data=data`. Documentation here: https://developers.cloudflare.com/api/operations/dns-records-for-a-zone-patch-dns-record

Comment: You're sending a `Content-Type: application/json` header, but the data you're sending is not actually json...